# What are these mini figures?

Tags: part-identification, minifigures, minifigure-identification

I have just brought these mini figures and was wondering if anyone could identify them?

[image: Numbered photo of minifigs]

Answer (score 5):

- 1 - [Kiteman](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sh336/kite-man) from : [70903-1: The Riddler Riddle Racer](https://brickset.com/sets/70903-1/The-Riddler-Riddle-Racer)
- 2 -  [Captain Jack Sparrow](https://brickset.com/minifigs/poc001/captain-jack-sparrow)
- 3 -  [lor037: Fili the Dwarf](https://brickset.com/minifigs/lor037)
- 4 - [hp108: Draco Malfoy, Dark Green and White Quidditch Uniform](https://brickset.com/minifigs/hp108)
- 5 - This torso (Darth Maul] - [Torso SW Layered Shirt, White Undershirt, Waist Sash Pattern / Black Arms / Black Hands](http://LegoTorso%20SW%20Layered%20Shirt,%20White%20Undershirt,%20Waist%20Sash%20Pattern%20/%20Black%20Arms%20/%20Black%20Hands)
- 6 - This torso; [Torso LotR Gold Ruffled Shirt, Reddish Brown Layered Pattern / Pearl Gold Arms / Light Flesh Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1281c01&idColor=88#T=C&C=88)
- 7 - [71011-1: Farmer from Collectable MinifiguresSeries 15](https://brickset.com/sets/71011-1/Farmer)
- 8 - This torso; [Torso LotR Cloak with Brown Collar and Straps Pattern (Legolas) / Olive Green Arms / Light Flesh Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1151c01#T=C&C=155). The hair is from #3 [Fili the Dwarf](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=lor036#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 9 - This torso; [Torso Castle Knights Kingdom Plate Armor Gold and Silver Female Pattern / Black Arms / Yellow Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=2780#T=C&C=10)
- 10 - [8831-10: Jungle Boy from Collectable Minifigures Series 07](https://brickset.com/sets/8831-10/Jungle-Boy)
- 11 - This torso; [Torso LotR Tank Top over Dark Green Shirt Pattern / Dark Green Arms / Light Flesh Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb1282c01&idColor=120#T=C&C=120) , Hair /head  [Legolas Greenleaf](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=lor035#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 12 - [71010-3: Monster Scientist from Collectable Minifigures Series 14](https://brickset.com/sets/71010-3/Monster-Scientist)
- 13 - [71002-3: Pretzel Girl from Collectable Minifigures Series 11](https://brickset.com/sets/71002-3/Pretzel-Girl)
- 14 - [sh012: Lex Luthor](https://brickset.com/minifigs/sh012/lex-luthor) from [6862-2: Superman vs. Power Armor Lex](https://brickset.com/sets/6862-2/Superman-vs-Power-Armor-Lex)
- 15 - This torso; [Torso SW Armor Clone Trooper Pattern / White Arms / Black Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0117c01#T=C)
- 16 - The head is from [Zolm - Hassansin Leader](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=pop012#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 17 - [71011-5: Tribal Woman from Collectable Minifigures Series 15](https://brickset.com/sets/71011-5/Tribal-Woman)
- 18 - [8827-13: Intergalactic Girl from Collectable Minifigures Series 06](https://brickset.com/sets/8827-13/Intergalactic-Girl)
- 19 - This torso; [Pirate Captain (5002147)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=col281#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)
- 20 - [71010-14: Banshee from Collectable Minifigures Series 14](https://brickset.com/sets/71010-14/Banshee)
- 21 - This torso; [Torso Harry Potter Quidditch Gryffindor Ribbed Pattern / Dark Red Arms / Reddish Brown Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973pb0747c01&idColor=59#T=C&C=59)
- 22 - [hp111: Hagrid, Dark Brown Topcoat with Buttons (Light Flesh Version with Moveable Hands)](https://brickset.com/minifigs/hp111/hagrid-dark-brown-topcoat-with-buttons-(light-flesh-version-with-moveable-hands)) (wrong hair)
- 23 - [71011-7: Faun from Collectable Minifigures Series 15](https://brickset.com/sets/71011-7/Faun)

The skate board is this one: [Minifig, Utensil Skateboard with Trolley Wheel Holders with Minifig Skull on Star and Winged Heart Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=42511pb07&in=S)

With thanks to Rin Rio-Oki